# Comics identification: Priests who are embodiment of 7 sins are venerated as saints

Tags: story-identification, comics

I read this comicbook 6-10 years ago. Can't find it but I would like to read it again.

The Serbian translation was titled something like "Seven holy men" or "Saints" or "Seven saints". The main protagonists are seven priests who each embody a deadly sin: there is the prideful one, lustful one, gluttonous one, wrathful one, slothful one, greedy one, envious one.

The first page shows a Viking shaman doing a ritual. After finishing it, Vikings go berserk and towards their ships, to start a war.

The last page shows the priestess and the prideful priest doing a similar (only Christian) ritual of asking the god to favor them in battle, then Vikings going berserk and to war.

Anyway, this is what I remember:

- The envious one started everything by reporting the others (except for the prideful one) for their sins to some version of Inquisition.
- They are judged and sentenced to death for breaking their priestly vows and heresy. But because the Vikings have attacked Christian settlements during the previous months, the envious one tells the court to change their sentence and to send the 5 to proselytize to the Vikings, because killing them would be a waste, and God is great, it might just work to soften the hearts of the Vikings etc etc.
- The Inquisition agrees, with one caveat: the envious one and the prideful one (who was high in the Church hierarchy and one of the judges) have to go with them! Something like that, I am not certain.
- They go on their way by ship. A few months later, while they're in a settlement, taking supplies, the settlement is attacked by the Vikings.
- The Seven are taken prisoners. But before the Vikings can take them back into their ships for a life of slavery, Christian soldiers arrive. At first, the Seven are elated, because they are saved.
- Unfortunately, the soldiers are from another nation and start killing Vikings and prisoners indiscriminately. One of the Seven dies (I think the envious one) by the sword of a Christian soldier.
- The wrathful one (who was a good friend of the dead one and was hurt by his treachery, but had forgiven him later) sees his death, attacks one of the Vikings, chokes him down with his bare chained hands and takes the Viking's sword. Then he goes berserk, cutting through both sides alike, killing everyone on his path (somehow, killing more Christian soldiers than Vikings), until he is literally too tired to stand and he sits down, covered in blood but still holding a sword. The Vikings recognize a berserker when they see one and remove his chains. The 6 are taken to the Viking village.
- The wrathful one joins Viking warriors, becomes a hunter for them, gets a wife and is happy, because he likes fighting and drinking and basically takes to Viking society like fish takes to water
- The lustful one starts sleeping with the Viking wives and converting them to Christianity with his charm
- The gluttonous one teaches the Vikings how to make wine and distill alcohol and farm better and starts hoarding food, which saves them all when famine arrives a few months later and he opens his food storage for the whole tribe to use, so as not to be killed by angry mob. But they play it off like it was his plan all along, he had vision from God where He told him to make a big food storage because drought will come next season or something like that. It makes the Christian God look more powerful than the Pagan Gods.
- The greedy one gets close with the village blacksmith and teaches him how to smelt gold, shave coins, clean ore impurities and hoards a large piece of gold from Viking raids with the blacksmith's help. This becomes important later.
- The slothful one becomes known as a great organizer and wise man, because he invents better ladders, winch, wheelbarrow and other things to make life easier, just so he wouldn't have to work hard. And generally he organizes builders and other workers efficiently, while not doing anything much himself.
- The prideful one gets close to the shaman's female helper and to the leader of the raid who took them, who has aspirations towards being a tribe leader. He starts playing politics of the tribe with gusto, as a prophet and advisor.
- Something climactic and apocalyptic happens during the choosing of the new leader. All I remember is that the shaman said one thing will happen and prideful one said that soon it will rain fire, gold and iron or something like that. The prideful one's prophecy came true when slothful's distillery was torched by the shaman or accidentally caught fire (it was close to the blacksmith) and exploded, thus blowing their whole hoarded gold everywhere around the town and raining fire, gold and iron. Some of the Six are killed in the process, I think.
- The Vikings are baptized, the Seven are now venerated as saints, with the face of the envious one carved as a face of Jesus on statues. The shaman's female helper who helped him become chief priest of the tribe becomes prideful one's wife and a Christian priestess. In reality, the society doesn't change that much, as evidenced by the last scene.

Comment: "*In translation*" - which languages?

Comment: Serbian. But that is not important. It is originally either USA or European comic.

Comment: Anyway, this is an amazingly thorough and detailed story-ID question! :-D

Comment: @Randal'Thor one might almost call it *exemplary*.

Comment: That's a damn good memory. I can barely remember what the cover looks like after 10 years.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

*Sept* (*Seven*) volume 4, "Sept missionnaires" ("Seven Missionaries") by Alain Ayroles and Luigi Critone, published in 2008?

It's part of a French "conceptual" series of seven unrelated comics, written and drawn by seven different teams (as part of a challenge launched by a comics writer), telling the missions of seven unrelated groups of people, in various time periods and settings (fantasy, SF, etc). It was later expanded to more than seven groups:

1. "Seven psychopaths"
2. "Seven thieves"
3. "Seven pirates"
4. "Seven missionaries"
5. "Seven warriors"
6. "Seven Yakuzas"
7. "Seven prisoners"
8. "Seven survivors"
9. "Seven characters"
10. "Seven clones"
11. Etc; there's 21 of them, refer to [that page](https://www.bedetheque.com/serie-15358-BD-Sept__1.html) for more info (in French).

Translated from [Bedetheque](https://www.bedetheque.com/BD-Sept-Tome-4-Sept-missionnaires-72256.html):

> Ireland, 9th century. Seven monks living in community have long since turned their backs on the sacred principles of the Church. Each one gives himself body and soul to his favourite sin: who to pride, who to envy, who to lust... But the wrath of the Most High will fall on these seven capital sinners, in the form of a perilous mission: to take to the sea and evangelize ferocious Vikings!

[image: cover with a hatchet and seven monks]

Here's your shamanic ritual:

[image: shamanic ritual]

---

Found with the Google query `bande dessinée sept saints vikings` (`comics seven saints vikings`).

Comment: That's the one. Thank you very much.

Comment: So it's a trilogy of seven books!